# Visual studio error An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am having an error on my c# windows form application, This error is only occurring on Windows 10 and it the program runs fine in windows 7.
Here is the part of the code that is not working.
Visual studio version: Community 2015
Thanks.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public struct Mypizzas
    {
        public string mypizzaname;
        public float mypizzaprice;
    }
    public struct Mypizzasordered
    {
        public string mypizzaname;
        public float mypizzaprice;
        public float QtyOrdered;

    }
    string newpizza;
    Mypizzasordered[] Orderlist = new Mypizzasordered[51];
    Single mytotalprice;
    string numpizzasordered;

    int countertest;
    int Mycounter;


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Mypizzas[] myarrayofpizzas = new Mypizzas[6];
        myarrayofpizzas[0].mypizzaname = ("Hawaiian");
        myarrayofpizzas[0].mypizzaprice = 3.99f;
        myarrayofpizzas[1].mypizzaname = "Margherita";
        myarrayofpizzas[1].mypizzaprice = 5.99f;
        myarrayofpizzas[2].mypizzaname = "Chicago Pizza";
        myarrayofpizzas[2].mypizzaprice = 4.99f;
        myarrayofpizzas[3].mypizzaname = "New York Style Pizza";
        myarrayofpizzas[3].mypizzaprice = 6.5f;
        myarrayofpizzas[4].mypizzaname = "Sicilian Pizza";
        myarrayofpizzas[4].mypizzaprice = 5.99f;



        for (Mycounter = 0; Mycounter <= 6; Mycounter++)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Add(myarrayofpizzas[Mycounter].mypizzaname);
            listBox2.Items.Add(myarrayofpizzas[Mycounter].mypizzaprice);
        }
    }
```

The error occurs on this line: listBox1.Items.Add(myarrayofpizzas[Mycounter].mypizzaname);

Comment: myarrayofpizzas is defined as MyPizzas[6].  Which means 0-5.  Your for loop covers 0 - 6.  Use `for (Mycounter = 0; Mycounter < 6; Mycounter++)
`

Comment: @JayBuckman - While that's true, it wouldn't create an ArgumentNullException.

Comment: Also, `myarrayofpizzas` is an array with 6 elements. However, you only initialize 5 elements. `mypizzaname` of the last element remains `null`. Note that i am not absolutely certain that this is causing the ArgumentNullException under Win10, but it's possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your actual code, then the problem is that you are only populating 5 items (0-4) with data.  So, when you go to add the 6th item (which is actually index 5) it has a null value for `mypizzaname`.  This is what throws the exception.

If you add an additional pizza, this problem will go away, but then you will have a different problem, which is that you will get an ArgumentOutOfBounds exception, which is caused by trying to access an array index that doesn't exist (a size 6 array can only have items 0-5, so accessing item 6 is actually the 7th item)

The easiest fix will be to change

```
for (Mycounter = 0; Mycounter <= 6; Mycounter++)
```

to

```
for (Mycounter = 0; Mycounter < 5; Mycounter++)
```

or

```
for (Mycounter = 0; Mycounter <= 4; Mycounter++)
```

The other way to fix it is to add an additional pizza and also change your counter.

```
myarrayofpizzas[5].mypizzaname = "New Pizza";
myarrayofpizzas[5].mypizzaprice = 5.99f;
...
for (Mycounter = 0; Mycounter < 6; Mycounter++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public struct Mypizzas
    {
        public string mypizzaname;
        public float mypizzaprice;
    }
    public struct Mypizzasordered
    {
        public string mypizzaname;
        public float mypizzaprice;
        public float QtyOrdered;

    }
    string newpizza;
    Mypizzasordered[] Orderlist = new Mypizzasordered[51];
    Single mytotalprice;
    string numpizzasordered;

    int countertest;
    int Mycounter;


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Mypizzas[] myarrayofpizzas = new Mypizzas[6];
        myarrayofpizzas[0].mypizzaname = ("Hawaiian");
        myarrayofpizzas[0].mypizzaprice = 3.99f;
        myarrayofpizzas[1].mypizzaname = "Margherita";
        myarrayofpizzas[1].mypizzaprice = 5.99f;
        myarrayofpizzas[2].mypizzaname = "Chicago Pizza";
        myarrayofpizzas[2].mypizzaprice = 4.99f;
        myarrayofpizzas[3].mypizzaname = "New York Style Pizza";
        myarrayofpizzas[3].mypizzaprice = 6.5f;
        myarrayofpizzas[4].mypizzaname = "Sicilian Pizza";
        myarrayofpizzas[4].mypizzaprice = 5.99f;



        for (Mycounter = 0; Mycounter < 6; Mycounter++)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Add(myarrayofpizzas[Mycounter].mypizzaname);
            listBox2.Items.Add(myarrayofpizzas[Mycounter].mypizzaprice);
        }
    }
```

You are looping 7 times, not 6.
0,1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: When i change the 6 to a 7 it still gives the error.

Comment: As I mentioned to Jay, that would generate an ArgumentOutOfRange exception, not an ArgumentNullException

Comment: It does create that error, However it doesn't create any errors when i run the code on a different system.

Comment: Is your ToString expecting mypizzaname or mypizzaprice  to have a value?  Also have you tried catching it and outputting what Mycounter equals?

Comment: @Tom The code you are running on a different system is different code.  Not the code you posted in your question.